# Argument 1 passed to App\Entity\Invitacion::setEmail() must be an instance of App\Entity\User or null - Symfony 4

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony4

I am new to Symfony4. I have a problem related to the value set in the table. I have been following the Symfony documentation. I want to store the user's **email** and **codeinvitations** variable in the invitation table, but it gives me an error.

Please help me to solve my problems.

These are my entities

**App / Entity / User.php**

```php
class User implements UserInterface, \Serializable
{
    (...)

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, unique=true)
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Invitacion", mappedBy="user")
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, unique=true)
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Invitacion", mappedBy="user")
     */
    private $codeinvitaciones;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Invitacion", mappedBy="user")
     */
    private $invitaciones;

    /**
     * User constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->invitaciones = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getEmail(): ?string
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function setEmail(string $email): self
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCodeinvitaciones(): ?string
    {
        return $this->codeinvitaciones;
    }

    public function setCodeinvitaciones(string $codeinvitaciones): self
    {
        $this->codeinvitaciones = $codeinvitaciones;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Invitacion[]
     */
    public function getInvitaciones(): Collection
    {
        return $this->invitaciones;
    }

    public function addInvitaciones(Invitacion $invitacion): self
    {
        if (!$this->invitaciones->contains($invitacion)) {
            $this->invitaciones[] = $invitacion;
            $invitacion->setCodeinvitaciones($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

}
```

**App / Entity / Invitacion.php**

```php
class Invitacion
{
    (...)

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\User", inversedBy="email")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\User", inversedBy="invitaciones")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $codeinvitaciones;


    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getEmail(): ?User
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function setEmail(?User $email): self
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCodeinvitaciones(): ?User
    {
        return $this->codeinvitaciones;
    }

    public function setCodeinvitaciones(User $codeinvitaciones): self
    {
        $this->codeinvitaciones = $codeinvitaciones;

        return $this;
    }

}
```

In the Controller I create the user when registering in a form. At the same time, I store the **email** and the variable **codeinvitations** in the table **invitation** but it gives me an error.

**Controller**

```php
(...)
$invitacion->setEmail($email);
$invitacion->setCodeinvitaciones($registroInv);
```

**ERROR**

```
Argument 1 passed to App\Entity\Invitacion::setEmail() must be an instance of App\Entity\User or null,
string given, called in C:\Users\adria\Documents\app\bebeBB\src\Controller\UserController.php on line 38
```

thanks

**--------------EDIT-----------**

I had already tried passing `Invitacion::setEmail(?string)` but it gives this error:

```
Expected value of type "App\Entity\User" for association field
"App\Entity\Invitacion#$codeinvitaciones", got "string" instead.
```

Comment: The error is quite self-explanatory, `setEmail` expects a `User` instance (or null), you are passing a string. Presumably (as your controller code is missing) you are doing `$email = $user->getEmail();`.Change `Invitacion::setEmail(?User)` to `Invitacion::setEmail(?string)` and its mapping or pass the whole `User` object.

Comment: I had already tried passing `Invitacion::setEmail(?string)` but it gives this error: 
`Expected value of type "App\Entity\User" for association field "App\Entity\Invitacion#$codeinvitaciones", got "string" instead.`

Comment: Yes, already pointed that out too. Your `$email` *mapping* in the `Invitacion` entity is of type `User`: `@ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\User")`. If you want a foreign key to the user table, you have to pass the `User` object and adjust all calls accordingly. If you don't need a reference and can live with denormalized data, change it to `string`.

Answer (score 0):

As already said in the comments setEmail(?User email) takes null or an User-object as input. I would suspect that you would want to enter the email-address there, so you could do:

Setter:

```
setEmail(?string $email)
```

Call:

```
$user = new User();
$user->setEmail('test@test.com');
$invitacion->setEmail($user->getEmail());
```

or if you really want to add a full user object as it is:

```
$user = new User();
$user->setEmail('test@test.com');
$invitacion->setEmail($user);
```

In both cases their has to be a user object first. Then you could access the object or mail for your setter.